# Web3.js with Angular not working

Tags: web3js, dapps, angular2, angularjs

I can't get web3.js to work with Angular. I got the exact same problem as the person [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66749738/angular-web3-js-module-not-found-error-cant-resolve-crypto).

I used method 2 from the answer on that question, and it seems to work as it now compiles, but I'm getting the following error in the console:
[image: screenshot of error]

Basically all solutions on the internet on this problem that I have tried lead to this error for me.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Problem had to do with an initialization of the Contract class from web3 like this:

```
new Contract([]);
```

Even though vscode says that it clearly needs at least one parameter in the constructor, it caused this error. I fixed it by setting it to null instead (this is about setting the initialState in redux).

I still don't understand why this issue occurs, as Contract needs parameters in the constructor, so if someone knows, please tell.